# How to find last month of rolling year in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a requirement in which I have to show the data of last month of each year. So I used a max_month LOD expression which is working fine for all the years except rolling year. My rolling year ranges from Aug 2017 to July 2018. Now when I am using max_month filter for rolling year it is showing me the data of december 2017, but in actual I want to show july 2018. What will be the right approach to fix this?

Comment: can you post the formula here?

Comment: Is your rolling year the same as a fiscal year?

Comment: Yes rolling year is same as fiscal year.And I have used the following code in the max_month calculated field.     If(MAX(MONTH(Datefield))=(WINDOW_MAX(MONTH(Datefield)) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' . Then I dragged the datefield to the rows shelf & filtered the max_month calculated field to 'TRUE'.

Comment: If you need to use a fiscal year, right-click on your date dimension, choose Default Properties, then choose Fiscal Year Start. This will adjust everything to behave like you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure even if your formula worked, its missing basic syntax, and based on your explanation table calculation is missing the `Computation` logic.

Implemented the same at my end and below is the logic.

Formula to be used:

```
If MAX(MONTH([Order Date]))=WINDOW_MAX(MAX(MONTH([Order Date])))
THEN 'TRUE'
ELSE 'FALSE'
END
```

For this table calculation  you need to compute along year and corresponding dimension and reset at every year (I guess you are missing this in your current logic).

Let me know how it goes

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong in the previous comment. I have used exactly the same logic what you are saying. It's giving me the data of december 2017 for rolling year.

Comment: What is your computation logic?

Comment: Actualy I am new in tableau. I don't know exactly how to implement computation logic with the formula you have mentioned above. I just created a bar chart with 'datefield and a dimension field' in the row shelf and a measure in the column shelf. Then I filtered out the data by selecting only 'True' with the above formula mentioned,and it's giving me dec 2017 data.